# How to do Multi-factor authentication with SharePoint-Online using CSOM

Tags: authentication, csom, sharepoint-online

Using just a password-based authentication, it's easy to authenticate in CSOM:

```
context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, password);
```

But how to authenticate when Multi-factor authentication is in place (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn249471.aspx)?

Comment: we decided to use oauth authentication to circumvent MFA

Comment: We thought about that, but how do you handle MFA in OAuth? You must still ask the user interactively to enter a pincode and you must write all code for that yourself, or is there a library for that?

Comment: My understanding is once you've got a token, you just authenticate ClientContext via injecting Bearer authentication into the request in ClientContext.ExecutingWebRequest without setting the credentials and using the password in any way - which should not trigger MFA.

Answer (score 2):

Use an app password in place of your normal one.

Generate an app password here:

https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/AppPasswords.aspx

Or go to

https://portal.office.com/account/#security

and click `Additional Security Verification` > `Create app password`.

You can always revoke/delete the app password later.